# SQL Delete Statement matching criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to perform a `DELETE` statement based on two matches. I keep receiving `0 Rows affected` in Sequel Pro (OSX).

```
DELETE FROM devices WHERE device_id = '99999999999' AND state != 'PENDING'
```

`device_id` is a `VARCHAR` and state is an ENUMERATED list.

Note: If I remove `AND state != 'PENDING'` , the query will perform the delete. However, I need to match on both criteria.

This seems to be a problem with `state` is `NULL`.

Comment: Well the obvious question is are you sure there's a row with `device_id = '9999999999'` with `state != 'PENDING'`?

Comment: I figured out the problem, but I find it strange. The state field for the device_id was NULL. I would assume != 'PENDING" should return success even if the value is NULL though. I discovered this by changing NULL to 'ACTIVE' - one of the accepted values of the ENUM list

Comment: `DELETE FROM devices WHERE (device_id = '99999999999' OR device_id IS NULL) AND state != 'PENDING'`

Comment: @ilikemypizza you need to check it for NULL also. What you want to do for the NULL State?

Comment: NULL is a special case and must be handled differently than other evaluations.  The simplest use would be to change your state to `coalesce(state,'') != 'PENDING'`

Comment: Shaikh, I just want to delete the record if it matches the device id and the state is anything but 'PENDING'. I will also check for null, thank you.

Comment: NULL is a special case in SQL.  It does not mean what it usually means in popular procedural or object-oriented languages.

Comment: ^^^^ why am I sooooo reminded of The Princes Bride.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NULL` cannot be compared using the `!=` operator (or similar operators) and the result will actually be `NULL`.  That is `SELECT 'PENDING' != NULL` actually selects `NULL` rather than `FALSE` or `TRUE`.  If the value can be `NULL` you have to use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` to check that and return the appropriate boolean.

```
AND (state != 'PENDING' OR state IS NULL)
```

Documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html

Comment: Explosion Pills, thank you! That would explain my problem. All solved! I will mark as solved once it lets me ;)